# Electric Displacement problem

Tags: dielectric

I'm studying Polarization, but I don't understand how i can solve the Gauss's law for vector D.
This is an example from the book. [image]. The author chooses a surface such that the magnitude, direction, and orientation of the vector D are constant on that surface allowing them to pull D out of the integral. But how can I do this if I don't know anything about the D field? How did the author know that along that surface D was constant in magnitude, direction, and direction if I don't know the behavior of the D field?

Comment: hint: forget the rubber first, can you guess the $E$ field just by the symmetry of the setup. Would the symmetry change if now you fill the empty space with rubber as the question is asking?

Comment: So you are telling me that the vector D has the same direction as the field E that generated the polarization?
That is, D follows direction of the field E generated by the wire?